# Cannot get what I should when doing 'fn.apply(null, arguments)' in the Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, arguments, apply

Here is functional code:

```
let fn = function() { console.log(arguments) }
let fn2 = function() { fn.apply(null, arguments) }
```

So after call `fn2(1,'t',4)` getting `Arguments { 0: 1, 1: "t", 2: 4, … }`.

But this code:

```
let def = { }

let p = new Promise((s,f)=>{
    def.s = function() { s.apply(null, arguments) }
    def.f = function() { f.apply(null, arguments) }
})

p.then(function(){
    console.log(arguments)
})
```

Returning after call `def.s(1,'T',2)` this `Arguments { 0: 1, … }`.

Tried in Chrome and Firefox. Am I missing something?
Thanks

Comment: What is `…` in that output?

Comment: a promise's resolve function takes a single argument, so, `'T'` and `2` are meaningless

Comment: Under `...` are hidden functions and other properties of arguments object. Check it out in the Firefox for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A promise can resolve only with a single value, and `then` callbacks are called with exactly one argument. Passing multiple things into `resolve` or `reject` is pointless. If you need all of them, pass them as a tuple value, as elements of an array.